# How do you convert a CSV file into a 2D array in Java or C++

Tags: java, c++, arrays, csv

My question title didn't fully outline my question. I have a text file that has many lines of data with each line in the following format:

```
a, date, b, c, d, Username, e, Description
```

a,b,c,d, and e will not need to be used for anything.

Notes:

- the dates are in this format -> 2013-04-07T22:23:58Z (the "T22:23:58Z" will not be needed)
- Descriptions are either login, logout, or extend
- same usernames will show up multiple times throughout the file

I need to write a code that will take the data from the text file, and output which users extended that day and how many times.

example of text file:

```
a,2013-04-07T22:23:58Z,b,c,d,john,extend
a,2013-04-07T22:23:51Z,b,c,d,john,login
a,2013-07-07T22:23:51Z,b,c,d,john,extend
a,2013-04-07T22:23:58Z,b,c,d,mark,extend
a,2013-03-07T22:23:51Z,b,c,d,frank,login
a,2013-07-11T22:23:51Z,b,c,d,john,extend
```

Example output:

```
2013-04-07:
john -> 1 extend
mark -> 1 extend

2013-07-07:
john -> 1 extend

2013-07-11:
john -> 1 extend
```

Can someone explain to me, or better yet show me how I can do this?

Comment: As a programming spec, this isn't that bad -- there's certainly enough info here for someone to do your work for you.  However, as a question, you left out the important bit - [what did you try on your own to answer your question?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Use a library - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Answer (score 0):

not really your required language, but here is a solution in awk :)

```
#!/bin/awk
BEGIN {
  FS=",";
}
/extend/{
    split($2,date,"T");
    dates[date[1],$6]++;
}
END {
  last = ""
  n = asorti(dates, dest)
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    split(dest[i], idx, SUBSEP)
    if ( last != idx[1]) {
      last = idx[1]
      print "\n"idx[1]
    }
    print idx[2] " -> " dates[idx[1], idx[2]] " extend"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

and another solution not in your required language.. PHP ;)

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$dates = array();

while (!feof($handle)) { 
    $data = explode(',', stream_get_line($handle, 200, "\n"));
    if (trim($data[6])=='extend') {
      @$dates[strstr($data[1], 'T', true)][$data[5]]++;
    }
} 

arsort($dates);

foreach ($dates as $date => $users) {
  echo $date;

  foreach ($users as $user => $times)
    echo "\n$user -> $times extend";

  echo '\n\n';
}

?>
```

use in console like this: ./script.php < input.txt